# Discussion on computing capability of Mathematica and CUDA C

Tags: polynomials, cuda

My research is computing on Legendre Polynomial, which will be done on Mathematica and optimized on GPU.

Now, My Mathematica program is completed and correct and I am working on translating it on CUDA.
When I run CUDA C code, the result is partially correct while the rest part is incorrect. I think the only reason that can explain is the difference of computing capability.

Here is my mathematica code of computing Legendre polynomial.

Legendre Polynomial:
[image: Legendre Polynomial]

Mathematica Code(Note that processing on array):

```
kXList = kXList1 = 
   ParallelTable[-1. + ((i - 1.) k + h) deltaX/k, {h, 1, k}, {i, 1, 
     W}];
kXList2 = ConstantArray[1., {k, W}];
xLegendreP = {Total[kXList2], Total[kXList1]};
Do[temp = (((2. n - 1.) kXList kXList1)/n) - (((n - 1.) kXList2)/n);
  kXList2 = kXList1;
  kXList1 = temp;
  xLegendreP = Join[xLegendreP, {Total[temp]}], {n, 2, Mmax}];
```

Simple demonstration on `kXList`: Dividing `x` to compute Polynomial more precisely. We can ignore it because it's unrelated to my question.

CUDA C kernel code:

```c
    int row = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    double delta = 2. / IMG_SIZE;
    if ((row < k) && (col < IMG_SIZE)) {
        kXList[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = -1. + (col * k + row + 1.) * delta/k;
        kXList_1[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = kXList[row * IMG_SIZE + col];
        kXList_2[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = 1.;
        double row_0 = 0.;
        double row_1 = 0.;
        for (int h = 0; h < k; h++) {
            row_0 += kXList_2[h * IMG_SIZE + col];
            row_1 += kXList_1[h * IMG_SIZE + col];
        }
        d_xLegendreP[0 * IMG_SIZE + col] = row_0;
        d_xLegendreP[1 * IMG_SIZE + col] = row_1;
        
        double row_n;
        for (int n = 2; n <= Mmax; n++) {
            kXList_temp[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = (((2. * n - 1.) * kXList[row * IMG_SIZE + col] * kXList_1[row * IMG_SIZE + col]) / n) - (((n - 1.) * kXList_2[row * IMG_SIZE + col]) / n);
            kXList_2[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = kXList_1[row * IMG_SIZE + col];
            kXList_1[row * IMG_SIZE + col] = kXList_temp[row * IMG_SIZE + col];
            row_n = 0.;
            for (int h = 0; h < k; h++) {
                row_n += kXList_temp[h * IMG_SIZE + col];
            }
            d_xLegendreP[n * IMG_SIZE + col] = row_n;
        }
    }
```

I print the first column of the results of both programs. Note that Mathematica result is correct.

[image][image: CUDA C result]

We can see that CUDAC result is incorrect starting from row 7(n=6). Theoretically, result should be totally incorrect or correct, because it's recursed from first two rows.

Comment: If Mathematica code works as it should then this is not the right forum.